# Junit: how can I pass a suite category through maven command line?

Tags: maven, jenkins, junit, automation, categories

I would like to set the category of a Junit suite dynamically, so that the category can be passed directly from the maven command line, for example. Something like this:

```
@RunWith(Categories.class)
@Categories.IncludeCategory(${Category}.class)
@Suite.SuiteClasses({

        MyTest1.class,
        MyTest2.class,
        (...)

})
```

Do you have an idea of how could I achieve that goal? The target is avoid creating a different suite per category, since there are so many. Thanks in advance for your answers.

I want to do this because I want to to be able to specify the category directly from Jenkins. Is there any way of passing a .class file as an argument or directly from the run time?

Comment: You can define the category on command line like this: `mvn clean test -Dgroups=Fast` or a like (https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/test-mojo.html) but you should not change the source code...

Comment: The thing is that my company has declared Junit suites, and we must use them. Is there a way of passing the category dynamically?